# Find all files that end with txt and out in all directories within a size margin

Tags: shell

Here is the code:

```
find /home/185053/ -iname "*.{txt,out}" -type f -size +8 -size -15
```

So, the command works if I exclude the `-iname "*.{txt,out}"` part out.

I've tried using `| grep "*.{txt,out}"` at the end but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: `"*.{txt,out}"` is invalid regex...

Answer (score 1):

Try using `grep` with `-E` option and like this:

```
find /home/185053/ -type f -size +8 -size -15 | grep -E "*\.txt|*\.out"
```